# Arduino serial monitor lagging and cant get it to work

Tags: c++, arduino

I wrote this program to check some things m but for me it is not working
` #define outputA 7
#define outputB 3

```
  int counter = 0; 
  int aState;
  int aLastState; 
  int StateAreTheSamePrinted = 0; 
  int StatePrinted = 0;


 void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
   pinMode(outputA, INPUT);
   pinMode(3, INPUT);

   Serial.begin(115200);
   aLastState = digitalRead(outputA);
   Serial.print("Arduino started");  
  }

 void loop() {

   // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
   aState = digitalRead(outputA);

   if(StatePrinted == 0)  
   {
    Serial.print(aState);
    StatePrinted = 1;  
   }    

   if(aState == aLastState && StateAreTheSamePrinted == 0)
   {
    Serial.print("States are the same");       
    StateAreTheSamePrinted = 1;
   }

  if(aState != aLastState)  
  {
    if(aState == 1){
      Serial.print("A is high \n");            
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print("A is low \n");
  }
  StateAreTheSamePrinted = 0;
  StatePrinted = 0;
 }  
  aLastState = aState;  
}
```

It always prints once arduino started, 1 (state of input), and states are the same, when I wire 5v from arduino into port 7, sometimes it react once, sometimes n ot, after few minutes it start priting output like 50-100 lines of messages and stops and lags again. Does anyone got into this problem?
`

I was expecting that after giving power into arduino 7 port it would print A is high or A is low and toggle between them

Comment: did you wire 0v after you wired 5V?

Comment: I wired gnd in pins near 13 pin to gnd close to 5V

Comment: what..........?

Comment: It seems like digitalRead(outputA) is not working

Comment: after you connected 5v to pin 7 did you disconnect 5v and connect 0v?

Comment: I wired ground port which I understand you mean by 0V

Comment: did you connect pin 7 to ground?

Comment: No, how I would connect it its only one pin?

Comment: let me put it this way: You said you made the pin go high, and it printed it was going high. So far, so good. But how did you make it go low?

Comment: I just remove it, and it should be low because no signal(eletricity) is coming in it

Comment: > `I just remove it, and it should be low` Please read the basics about digital input. 
E.g. look at the basic examples on arduino.cc

Comment: that isn't how it works. Removing does not make it low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to "debounce" after the state changes. When you hook 5v into the pin, it might not make a stable connection right away so it changes state very quickly a few times. A simple fix is to put a ~10ms delay after it detects a state change.